# Using an Iterator for a Java ArrayList rather than c-style loop

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, time-complexity

When iterating through a LinkedList, get(i) is an O(N) operation. It makes sense then that we use an Iterator object to traverse the list. But with an ArrayList, get(i) is O(1). So, in that case am I correct in saying that when using an ArrayList, it doesn't make a difference whether we use a c-style loop or an Iterator object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. You should avoid loops like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < linkedList.size(); i++) {
    ... linkedList.get(i) ...
}
```

for a `LinkedList` because `get(i)` is `O(n)` so the whole process becomes `O(n^2)`.

For an `ArrayList` it does not matter as both `iterator.next()` and `get(i)` are `O(1)`.

However, you usually do not need to explicitly use an `Iterator` object even for a `LinkedList` because a foreach loop `for (Object object : linkedList)` uses an `Iterator` in the background anyway.

`Iterator`s only need to be used explicitly in relatively rare situations (e.g. filtering a `List` or traversing two `LinkedList`s in parallel).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be `O(n)` in both cases for `ArrayList`. If you're using the iterator to look up an element, in the worst case you would have to check every element. In the average case you would have to check half. Hence it's still `O(n)`.

Also, the `for` syntax for iterating over a list is just syntactic sugar for invoking the iterator. If you look at the compiled bytecode, you will see that it invokes the iterator for the list.

For example, the following code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class IterTest {

    public static void main() {
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();

        for(String s : l) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Has the following bytecode:

```
Compiled from "IterTest.java"
public class IterTest {
  public IterTest();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main();
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class java/util/ArrayList
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/util/ArrayList."<init>":()V
       7: astore_0
       8: aload_0
       9: invokeinterface #4,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
      14: astore_1
      15: aload_1
      16: invokeinterface #5,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
      21: ifeq          44
      24: aload_1
      25: invokeinterface #6,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
      30: checkcast     #7                  // class java/lang/String
      33: astore_2
      34: getstatic     #8                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      37: aload_2
      38: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      41: goto          15
      44: return
```

You can see that it's using the iterator to loop over the list.

**UPDATE**

In response to your comment:

Your `for` loop with an index will have the same performance as the explicit iterator and the `for` iterator-style loop if you are using an `ArrayList`.

However, using the `for` with an index with a `LinkedList` will be strictly worse (on average) than the `ArrayList`, since for each index, you are performing an *O(n)* lookup. Hence, your total performance actually ends up being *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

Comment: What if I loop like this: for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++){//do stuff which involves myList.get(i)} 
Surely that's also just O(n), since myList.get(i) is constant time? In which case it doesn't matter if I use an Iterator or not?

Comment: @orrymr Yes, that is `O(n)` as well. Technically it doesn't matter since the performance for traversing the `ArrayList` is the same in all cases. I prefer using the `for` iterator-syntax since it is much more readable. But it may be that in some cases, it is more idiomatic to use the iterator or a `for` loop with an index.

Answer (score 0):

Using an `Iterator` is less error-prone when removing elements, compared to a while loop, because you don't have to adjust some position value (i, cursor, whatever you call it) when removing. A for loop is already using the iterator, as @Vivin Paliath explained, and doesn't work with removals (removals will cause `ConcurrentModificationException`s).